# How to unpack xx.tar.z files types?

Tags: windows, format, filesystems, unzip

I have installed a software that unpacks .zip and .tar files. However
I was wondering how do you unpack this kind of files myxxx.tar.z?

I have Tugzip installed but cannot open such .tar.z file format. 
Also how do you zip such files?

Answer (score 1):

The most famous app to do this kinda stuff is the **Winrar**. Did you tried with it? You can try the **7zip** too.

Comment: I haven`t. Is is command line based? or does it unpacks like regular zips files.

Comment: They are programs and unpack like regular zip files. But I guess some of tar.z could be installers, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

If your working on linux, you can do,

To decompress:

`tar -zxvf myxxx.tar.z`

To compress:

`tar -czvf your-file.tar.z your-files`

Comment: I am working on windows and also with makefiles. Is there a windows command line auto tool that can handle these files?

Comment: You can install 7zip(http://www.7-zip.org/). It supports a lot of formats